# Restrict Admin/ access to anonymous users and not admins django

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a new app:

> newApp

with 3 users

> [admin, user1, user2]

and a login page (not from /admin/). Is it possible to restrict/redirect access to django's Admin login? i want to just get into the admin/ path if the user logged IS and admin, That means it should not work if im not logged nor logged as normal user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im adding this answer because the one provided by Pedro couldnt answer the part that i was trying to figure out, not letting anyone access to the /admin/ path.

I used [Django-Decorator-Include](https://github.com/twidi/django-decorator-include) to mix it with Pedro's custom decorator

and the result on my urls.py is:

```
from decorator_include import decorator_include
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied

def user_is_admin(function):
    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.is_staff:
            return function(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            raise PermissionDenied
    return wrap

urlpatterns = [
    .....
    path('admin/', decorator_include([user_is_admin], admin.site.urls)),
    .....
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom view decorator to check if user is admin, and if not raise a Http404, for example:

```
def user_is_admin(function):
    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.is_admin:
            return function(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            raise Http404
    return wrap
```

user.is_admin would be a custom implementation, just an example. Now you just need to wrap your views

```
@user_is_admin
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

Comment: But how can i use it for the /admin/ page?